# Using .NET EF CORE, can i copy the whole database to a different server?

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, console-application, ef-core-2.0

I would like to create a simple console app that automatically copies the database from one server to another... I want the logic to be loosely coupled with the models...

The logic should work as long as the app has access to both servers.

I don't want to create a backup, I want to access the live database on one server and copy it to another without first backing it up.

Can .NET EF Core do that for SQL Server database?

Comment: You can create a backup and restore this on any server in any code that allow you to execute TSQL and if they share a file system / same domain etc, else you would need to script the table definitions and then execute this on the other server, after that copy the data from one server to another. better use SQL Server Management objects for that

Comment: i dont want to create a backup, i want to access the full database and copy it without first backing it up

Comment: You want to copy structure or data or both of them?

Comment: both the schema, and the data.

Comment: @McKabue have a look at https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/137853/Cloning-the-Entity-object-and-all-related-children

Answer (score 1):

Using backup is by far the best way. It also guarantees transactional consistency. If transactional consistency is for some reason not important, you can use `bcp`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-and-export-bulk-data-by-using-the-bcp-utility-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017